# Keep selected value from select

Tags: php, select

I'm trying to keep the selected value when the user selects a month and then submits. What I have prints the correct months from the array but I can't get $selected to actually select the month that was chosen previously.

```
<select name="month">
<option value="" disabled selected>By Month</option>
<option value="">-- All --</option>
<?php
$months = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );
foreach ($months as $month => $monthvalue):
$selected = ($month->month == strval(@$_GET['month'])) ? ' selected' : '';                
echo "<option value=\"$monthvalue\"$selected>$monthvalue</option>";
endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Try `$selected = ($monthvalue == strval(@$_GET['month'])) ? ' selected' : '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Honza Haering said, you need to check the value you got from the form (the one in the `$_GET` array) with `$monthvalue`.
I am surprised that `$month->month` does not give an error since `$month` should be an integer, not an object.

Personally, in a foreach loop I avoid using a variable for the array key unless I really need it.

Comment: You're right! Thank you! Still a noob. Changing $month->month to $monthvalue makes it work.

Comment: You might want to check the error level config option. It is good not to print errors on the production server but it's also good to have all them on while you develop. Notice errors might not halt the execution but they often indicate a bug waiting to happen.